# Tensorflow Op: how to include libtensorflow_framework.so?

Tags: c++, c++11, ubuntu, tensorflow

I followed the instructions of this tutorial:
https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op#implement_the_gradient_in_python.
There is this comment provided: `g++ -std=c++11 -shared zero_out.cc -o zero_out.so -fPIC -I$TF_INC -I$TF_INC/external/nsync/public -L$TF_LIB -ltensorflow_framework -O2`

But the linker cannot find `-ltensorflow_framework` (it should be a tensorflow_frameowork.so file!?)

After some research, I found following links:

- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1569
- https://github.com/eaplatanios/tensorflow_scala/issues/26 --> I downloaded the .jar and linked it via `-l/pathto/tensorflow_framework.so`, still the `fatal error: tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h: No such file or directory` is not found.
- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1270  last comment does not work and so does not help me.

I tried to search for `sudo find /usr/. -name "tensorflow_framework.so"` recursively but I could not find anything. Tensorflow is installed for sure via anaconda and I also cloned and compiled the repository from source.

How to find a way to include the `-ltensorflow_framework`?

Comment: If none of the above work try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73868902/9824200

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One answer, I have found:

I have installed my python via anaconda2 and I always tried to find out TF_INC and TF_LIB when I activated my repository `source activate <env>`. and the could not found any `~/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow`
 *.so files

This time I went out every python environment with the shell command `source deactivate` and I typed the following command
`python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.sysconfig.get_lib())'`

Now, I got a different path: `~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow`, where the lib `libtensorflow_framework.so` is located.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the file `libtensorflow_framework.so.1` existed inside my `TF_LIB` directory instead of `libtensorflow_framework.so`. In order to solve this issue, I had to create a symbolic link as follows:

```
ln -s libtensorflow_framework.so.1 libtensorflow_framework.so
```

Source: [Tensorflow NotFoundError: libtensorflow_framework.so: cannot open shared file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56888781/tensorflow-notfounderror-libtensorflow-framework-so-cannot-open-shared-file-or)

Answer (score 0):

tensorflow_framework is not used before Tensorflow 1.4.1

When you call python from the shell make sure you are calling the right one:

TF_LIB = $(shell python -c 'import tensorflow; print(tensorflow.sysconfig.get_lib())')

or

TF_LIB = $(shell python3 -c 'import tensorflow; print(tensorflow.sysconfig.get_lib())')

Answer (score 0):

To be more clear:

1. Get the path from `python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.sysconfig.get_lib())'`, and there is a libtensorflow_framework.so.1 inside the directory. Say `/home/.../lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/libtensorflow_framework.so.1`
2. Run `ln -s /home/.../lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/libtensorflow_framework.so.1 /home/.../lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/libtensorflow_framework.so`